# Hive 3.1.3 decimal arithmetic precision loss

Tags: hive

When casting values like this it works:

```
select cast(0.00000000 as decimal(38, 8)) + cast(0.00000014 as decimal(38, 8))
```

Result:

```
+---------+
|   _c0   |
+---------+
| 1.4E-7  |
+---------+
```

However with a table there is precision loss.

```
create table test_decimal(
 f1 decimal(38,8),
 f2 decimal(38,8)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

insert into test_decimal values(0.00000000,0.00000014);

select f1+f2 from test_decimal;
```

Result:

```
+---------+
|   _c0   |
+---------+
| 1.0E-7  |
+---------+
```

Why is there precision loss? Couldn't find any reference to this issue.